# Firefox - How to quickly open detele history dialog in private mode?

Tags: firefox, private-browsing

In private mode, Firefox disables "Clear recent history... (Ctrl+Shift+Del)" button.

But there still is a way to open "detele history" dialog in private mode:

Tools > Settings > [Privacy & Security] > scroll to History section > Click Clear History.

[image: Firefox Private mode Clear history.JPG]

But this is too risky to use, what if I accidentally change some settings while I'm trying to delete history.

I need to open this dialog because I want to clear the Data part (Site preferences, Offline website data).

Is there any way I can bring this button outside of settings menu? or can I open this dialog with command-line?

Comment: I mean, you could also not do what you oughtn't do on the computer, because that's what this question is screaming: how do I clear all traces of the iffy sites I wasn't supposed to visit?

Comment: @music2myear - ha ha, did you think I visit some illegal website? if I do that I'd use VPN, cause clean things on my PC won't clean things from the log of the internet provider. I clean things because I just want my PC to be clean.